# Retreiving queryparams from url in angular

Tags: angular

I am not being able to see the queryparams in my url after clicking the desired buttons

here is my code

html file

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">

<div class="col-md-5 ">
<div class="list-group">
  <a class="list-group-item " [routerLink]="['/product']" 
  [queryParams]="{category:Bread}"
  >Bread</a>

  <a class="list-group-item " [routerLink]="['/product']"
  [queryParams]="{category:Dairy}"
  >Dairy</a>

  <a class="list-group-item " [routerLink]="['/product']"
  [queryParams]="{category:Fruits}"
  >Fruits</a>

  <a class="list-group-item " [routerLink]="['/product']"
  [queryParams]="{category:SeasoningsandSpices}"
  >Seasonings and Spices</a>

  <a class="list-group-item " [routerLink]="['/product']"
  [queryParams]="{category:Vegetbales}"
  >Vegetables</a>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

i am only redirected to the page that has the routing link of '/product'
but not seeing queryparams on the url and also how do i retrieve it if have queryparams ?
here is the ss

https://ibb.co/DR0p9gz

Answer (score 1):

> but not seeing queryparams on the url

You are passing value of `queryParam` as static value so you need to wrap it within quotes like this -

```
<a class="list-group-item " [routerLink]="['/product']" 
  [queryParams]="{category:'Bread'}"
  >Bread</a>
```

> how do i retrieve it if have queryparams

And to get query Params in the component use code like this in the constructor -

```
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){
      this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
         // get params here with key name
      });
    }
```

Comment: To explain briefly, you OP are trying to pass variables called `Bread/Dairy/Fruits`, while @Pardeep is sending strings. That's why your code isn't working, while his should be.

Comment: @trichetriche thanks, you can edit my answer if you want to

Comment: nah a comment is enough, don't worry !

Answer (score 0):

Use `ActivatedRoute` to get params from URL

```
private route: ActivatedRoute
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
         // get params
      });
```